# Как пропустить определённую строку содержащий определённый текст

Tags: windows, cmd, bat, dos

Долго ломал голову, так и не нашёл решение. Нужно просто пропустить строку с текстом NetFx4-AdvSrvs

```
for /f %%a 
in ('%DISM% /Image:"%Mount%" /Get-Features /Format:table ^|find "| Enabled"') 
do (%DISM% /Image:"%Mount%" /Disable-Feature:%%a)
```

Comment: надо пустить в обработку **NetFx4-AdvSrvs** или игнорировать(пропустить) эту строку?

Comment: @Daemon-5 игнорировать(пропустить) эту строку и если можно(если есть такая возможность) то пример с несколькими строками.

Comment: можно и фильтры-исключения добавить, то есть, после последнего **^|find "| Enabled"**  - добавить **^|find/v"NetFx4-AdvSrvs"**. Если надо еще исключение (например текст *String2*), то еще добавить **^|find/v"String2"**. Либо всё одной командой **^|findstr/v "NetFx4-AdvSrvs String2"**

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=1 delims= " %%a in ('%DISM% /Image:"%Mount%" /Get-Features /Format:table ^|find "| Enabled"') do (
    if not "%%a"=="NetFx4-AdvSrvs" if not "%%a"=="Microsoft-Windows-NetFx4-US-OC-Package" if not "%%a"=="Microsoft-Windows-NetFx4-WCF-US-OC-Package" (
        %DISM% /Image:"%Mount%" /Disable-Feature:%%a
    )
)
```